# API: Loading user details using J Query and AJAX without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I am new to Ajax and Jquery.

1)I am trying to add a new user using post method via a form which is in HTML Modal. On clicking Submit button the Modal isn't closing on its own and I have to hit refresh for seeing whether user got added or not. What changes should I do?

2)After checking whether the email and passwords match for a particular user during login how can I display the user details on successful login?

```js
Here is my JS code:   
             
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#retrieve").click(function(){
                        $('#retrieve').css("display","none");
                        // $('#uploadimageform').css("display","none");
                        $('#tabledata').css("display","block");
                        $('#signupbtn').css("display","block");
                        $('#loginbtn').css("display","none");
                    });
                });
                
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#backbutton").click(function(){
                        $('#retrieve').css("display","block");
                        // $('#uploadimageform').css("display","block");
                        $('#tabledata').css("display","none");
                        $('#signupbtn').css("display","block");
                        $('#loginbtn').css("display","block");
                    });
                });

                // $(document).ready(function(){
                //     $("#addbutton").click(function(){
                //       $('#myModal').css("display","none");  

                //     });


                // });
           
                $(function () {
                   
                    var $orders = $('#orders');

                    var $fname = $('#first');
                    var $lname = $('#last');
                    var $contact = $('#contact');
                    var $addr1 = $('#addr1');
                    var $addr2 = $('#addr2');
                    var $strt = $('#strt');
                    var $strt1 = $('#strt1');
                    var $city = $('#city');
                    var $statee = $('#statee');
                    var $cntry = $('#cntry');
                    var $email = $('#email');
                    var $paswrd = $('#paswrd');
                    var $gndr = $('#gndr');

                    // Getting the user from backend. Method is "GET". 
                    $.ajax({

                        type:'GET',
                        url:'http://13.229.164.32/users.json',

                        success:function(orders){
                            orders = orders.sort(function(a, b){
                                return a.id-b.id
                            })
                            
                            $.each(orders,function(id,order){
                                $orders.append('<tr><td>'+ order.id +
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit firstname">' + order.firstname + '</span><input value=' + order.firstname + ' name="firstname" class="edit firstname_'+order.id+'"/>' +  
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit lastname">' +  order.lastname+  '</span><input  value=' + order.lastname + ' name="lastname" class="edit lastname_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit contact_number">' + order.contact_number + '</span><input value=' + order.contact_number + ' name="contact_number" class="edit contact_number_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit address1">' + order.address1 + '</span><input value=' + order.address1 + ' name="address1" class="edit address1_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                               
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit address2">' + order.address2 + '</span><input value=' + order.address2 + ' name="address2" class="edit address2_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                               
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit street">' + order.street + '</span><input value=' + order.street + ' name="street" class="edit street_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                               
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit street1">' + order.street1 + '</span><input value=' + order.street1 + ' name="street1" class="edit street1_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                               
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit city">' + order.city + '</span><input value=' + order.city + ' name="city" class="edit city_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                               
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit state">' + order.state + '</span><input value=' + order.state + ' name="state" class="edit state_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit country">' + order.country + '</span><input value=' + order.country + ' name="country" class="edit country_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit email">' + order.email + '</span><input type="email" value=' + order.email + ' name="email" class="edit email_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit password">' + order.password + '</span><input type="password" value=' + order.password + ' name="password" class="edit password_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<span class="noedit gender">' + order.gender + '</span><input value=' + order.gender + ' name="gender" class="edit gender_'+order.id+'"/>' +
                                               
                                    '</td><td>' + order.created_at +
                                    '</td><td>' + order.updated_at +
                                    '</td>' +
                                              
                                    '<td><button class="remove" data-id=' + order.id + '>X</button></td>' +
                                    '<td><button class="editOrder noedit">Edit</button></td>' +
                                    '<td><button class="saveEdit edit"  data-id=' + order.id + '>Save</button></td>' +
                                    '<td><button class="cancelEdit edit">Cncl</button>' +
                                              
                                    '</td><td>' + '<input type="file"/ name="user_photo" class="edit user_photo">' +
                                    '<img src="http://13.229.164.32/users/user_photo?id='+order.id+'" class="noedit user_photo_' + 
                                    order.id + '" height="80" width="80" >' + 
                                    '</td></tr>');
                            });
                        },
                            error:function(){
                                alert('error in testing');
                            }
                    });
               
                // Creating the user and method is "POST"
                $('#addbutton').on('click',function(){ 
                    var myForm =  document.getElementById("uploadimageform");
                    var data = new FormData(myForm);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,
                        processData:false,
                        contentType:false,
                        dataType:"json",
                        url: 'http://13.229.164.32/users.json', 
                        success: function(nData){
                            alert('user added');

                        }.bind(this),
                        error: function() {
                            alert('There is a problem with server in saving records');
                        }
                    });
                });
                   
                $orders.delegate('.remove','click',function(){
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var self = this;
                    var checkstr =  confirm('are you sure you want to delete this?');
                    if(checkstr == true){
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'GET',
                            url: 'http://13.229.164.32/users/user_delete.json?id=' +  $(this).attr('data-id') ,
                            success: function(){
                                //add delete pop up
                                $tr.fadeOut(300, function(){
                                    $(this).remove();
                                });
                            }
                        });                      
                    }else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                   
                    $orders.delegate('.editOrder','click',function(){
                       var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                       $tr.addClass('edit');
                    })

                    $orders.delegate('.cancelEdit','click',function(){
                       var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('edit');
                       
                    })
                  


                    $orders.delegate('.saveEdit', 'click', function(){
                        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var self = this;
                        var user_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

                        var formData = new FormData(); 
                        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("user_photo").files.length; 
                        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) 
                            { 
                                var file = document.getElementById("user_photo").files[i]; 
                                formData.append("user_photo", file);
                            } 
                        alert(user_id);
                        console.log(formData);

                        formData.append("user[firstname]", $(".firstname_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[lastname]", $(".lastname_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[gender]",  $(".gender_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[address1]", $(".address1_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[address2]", $(".address2_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[street]", $(".street_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[street1]", $(".street1_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[contact_number]", $(".contact_number_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[email]", $(".email_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[password]", $(".password_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[city]", $(".city_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[state]", $(".state_"+user_id).val());
                        formData.append("user[country]", $(".country_"+user_id).val());


                        console.log(formData);


                    $.ajax({

                            // headers: {
                            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                            // },

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://13.229.164.32/users/user_update.json?id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') ,
                        data: formData, 
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false, 
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(nData){
                            $tr.find('span.firstname').html(formData.firstname);
                            $tr.find('span.lastname').html(formData.lastname);
                            $tr.find('span.gender').html(formData.gender);
                            $tr.find('span.address1').html(formData.address1);
                            $tr.find('span.address2').html(formData.address2);
                            $tr.find('span.street').html(formData.street);
                            $tr.find('span.street1').html(formData.street1);
                            $tr.find('span.contact_number').html(formData.contact_number);
                            $tr.find('span.email').html(formData.email);
                            $tr.find('span.password').html(formData.password);
                            $tr.find('span.city').html(formData.city);
                            $tr.find('span.state').html(formData.state);
                            $tr.find('span.country').html(formData.country);
                            $tr.find('span.user_photo').html(formData.user_photo);
                            // addUser1(newUser);
                            // console.log(newUser);
                            $tr.removeClass('edit');
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert('error saving user');
                        }

                    });

                });

                $('#checkbutton').on('click',function(){ 
                    var self = this;
                    var email = $('#emailer').val();
                    var txtpaswrd = $('#paswrder').val();
                            


                          $.ajax({
                          type: "GET",
                          // data: data,
                          processData:false,
                          contentType:false,
                          dataType:"json",
                          url: 'http://13.229.164.32/users/user_check.json?email=' + email, 
                          success: function(nData){

                            alert(nData.password);
                            alert(nData.email);
                            if(email == nData.email && txtpaswrd == nData.password ){

                                  alert('user details matched ');

                          }else{ 
                              alert('Password Error');
                         }
                       
                    }

                           


                          });

                    });
    });
                        
                //     });
                // });
```

```css
Here is my CSS code:
.container{
    margin:50px; 

            }

table,tr,th,td{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

tr .edit{
     display: none;
}

tr.edit .edit{
     display: initial;
}

tr.edit .noedit{
     display: none;
}
.btn{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#loginhere{
   
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
}
p.sign{
    margin-left: 50%;
}

select, input{
      width:50%;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }

input#user_photo{
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#signupbtn{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
Here is my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery.ajax()</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="api2.css">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- For making a modal for pop up displaying the form for adding users.-->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- For Signup button-->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="signupbtn" >Sign Up</button>
            <!-- For Login button-->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModall" id="loginbtn" >Login</button><br>
            
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Form for adding user details.-->
                            <form id="uploadimageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="first name" id="first" maxlength="15" name="user[firstname]" /><br />
                                <input type="text" placeholder="last name" id="last" maxlength="15" name="user[lastname]" /><br />
                                <input type="number" maxlength="10" placeholder="contact no." id="contact" name="user[contact_number]" /><br />
                                <input  type="address" placeholder="address1" id="addr1" name="user[address1]"/><br />
                                <input  type="address" placeholder="address2" id="addr2" name="user[address2]"/><br />
                                <input  type="address" placeholder="street" id="strt" name="user[street]"/><br />
                                <input  type="address" placeholder="street1" id="strt1" name="user[street1]"/><br />
                                <input  type="address" placeholder="city" id="city" name="user[city]"/><br />
                                <input  type="address" placeholder="state" id="statee" name="user[state]"/><br />
                                <input  type="address" placeholder="country" id="cntry" name="user[country]" /><br />
                                <input  type="email" placeholder="email" id="email" name="user[email]" /><br />
                                <input  type="password" placeholder="password" id="paswrd" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$" name="user[password]" /><br />
                                <!-- select for gender -->
                                <!-- <input  type="text" placeholder="gender" id="gndr" name="user[gender]" required/><br>-->

                                <!-- <label id="gndr" name="user[gender]" required>Gender
                                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                    <option value="Others">Other</option>
                                </label>
 
                                <label id="gndr" name="user[gender]" required>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked> Male<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other"> Other
                                </label>
-
                                <input type="file"   id="image" placeholder="Upload Image"/><br>-->


                                <select name="user[gender]" id="gndr">
                                <option>Gender</option>
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                </select><br />
                                <input type="file" name="user_photo" id="user_photo" /><br>
                                <div class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="addbutton" onclick="">Submit </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--add the form into a modal-->



            <div class="modal fade" id="myModall" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="uploadimageformm">
                                
                            <input  type="email" placeholder="email" id="emailer" name="user[email]" />
                            <input  type="password" placeholder="password" id="paswrder" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$" name="user[password]" />
                            
                                
                            <div class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="checkbutton" onclick="">Login </div>
                            </form>
                            <div id="ack"></div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            <div style="display:none;" id="tabledata">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr> 
                            <th>ID</th> 
                            <th>First Name</th> 
                            <th>Last Name</th> 
                            <th>Contact No.</th> 
                            <th>Address1</th> 
                            <th>Address2</th> 
                            <th>Street</th> 
                            <th>Street1</th> 
                            <th>City</th> 
                            <th>State</th> 
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Email</th> 
                            <th>Passowrd</th> 
                            <th>Gender</th> 
                            <th>Created At</th> 
                            <th>Updated At</th> 
                            <th>Remove Row</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Save</th>
                            <th>Cancel</th>
                            <th>User Pic</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody id="orders"></tbody>
                </table>
            
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="retrieve" onclick="">Retrieve List</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="backbutton" onclick="">Back</button>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxfetching.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please don't let us decrypt your entire app code and focus on the part you are asking on. 
My first guess regarding your issue is that your function executing the ajax call is missing a "preventDefault" if the event comes from a "<submit>" or "<button type="submit">" button.

Comment: Why do you have 2 jquerys linked?

Comment: In the HTML page, the modal for adding a new user creates a pop up where details of the new user are entered. On hitting the submit button the modal should close and my retrieve page should show the newly added user without refreshing the page. But this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Use on of the jQuery ajax callback to handle your modal close once your ajax call is done.

And then you need to refresh your page content to show the user created. I think the part of your code displaying user is the part with the Ajax call to "url:'http://13.229.164.32/users.json'". You need to call this again after you closed the modal, to rebuild your Page Content with the new content.

```
$('#addbutton').on('click',function(){ 
                var myForm =  document.getElementById("uploadimageform");
                var data = new FormData(myForm);
                $.ajax({...}).complete(... // handle your modal close + content reload here)
```

See [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation to use the proper callback.

2/ If your Authentication endpoints send user informations on successful login you could directly use them. If not, you will have to create an endpoint to get a specific user. Or alternatively, you could find the user in your "users.json" if you don't have hand on the API.

To reach an optimal result there are a lot of other optimizations to perform, but this should do the job in the first time. You are using $(document).ready(...) twice, then $(function(){...}) which is also similar.

Comment: /window.location.replace(' http://13.229.164.32/users.json?id=' + $(this).attr('data-id'));         I tried using this to get a particular user's details but it ain't helping.

Comment: how could window.location.replace help you find a user in a json ?

Comment: Yep I got the issue fixed. Thanks tho for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in the comment you will need to have a method to catch the submit handler, like prevent default. If you want to build your own button component that will fire the ajax method you may also do that.

Since your using jQuery, you may do the following;

```
$("#formId").submit(function (event) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
 // Run client validation,
 $.ajax({...options})
   .done(function(data){ 
     // do something with the data, like closing the modal
   })
   .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){ 
    // should the method fail, present error in the modal? 
   });
}
```

What you do in the button handler is up to you. 
[Jquery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

You may also set up your own button, and button click event, but since your using a form, when a user presses the enter key they will submit the form, and you must prevent that event from happening, should you go that route.